# Cakephp problemas com .htaccess

Tags: cakephp, htaccess

Efetuei a publicação do projeto, rodou corretamente, porém, os outros projetos que estavam na raiz deixaram de funcionar, verifiquei e pelo que notei o problema é no .htaccess, que está assim no momento:

```
php_value date.timezone 'America/Sao_Paulo'
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine     on
  RewriteRule    ^image/(.*)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$ app/webroot/thumb.php?$1 [QSA,L]

  RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Se eu colocar os outros projetos dentro da pasta /webroot eles funcionam, mas fica com URL **/app/webroot/projeto**

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Estou supondo que esse arquivo esteja no diretório principal (**app**) de seu novo projeto.</strike> Editado: seu **htaccess** está na raiz do host.

O **.htaccess** que voce postou está reescrevendo mais URLs do que devia.

Experimente mudar esse arquivo para:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^([^/]+)/image/(.*)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$ $1/app/webroot/thumb.php?$2 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule    ^([^/]+)$    $1/app/webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    ([^/]+)/(.*) $1/app/webroot/$2    [L]
</IfModule>
```

A idéia aqui é capturar o diretório principal de cada projeto no começo de cada URL e colocar antes do **app/webroot**. A captura ficará em `$1` e o que anteriormente estava em `$1` passa a ficar em `$2`.

Comment: O que está em (app) está dessa forma, este seria o da raiz antes da pasta (app), é como se direcionasse tudo com base na pasta webroot do cake.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta. Infelizmente não tenho como testar, mas espero que te leve na direção certa.